# Is there a way to have a ec2 resource run a command before it is destroyed?

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I am creating VM using terraform. Now I want to run some command using remote-exec on that VM before it destroyed.

Is there any way to this?

Thanks

Comment: You could try using the `when = destroy` with the `remote-exec` provisioner, but not sure if that will work.

Comment: @MarkoE From what I recall doing that several years ago, that did work. However, my memory is not perfect.

Comment: Yeah, I know it works for the `local-exec` provisioner, but I don't think I have tried that with the `remote-exec`.

Comment: I tried 'when = destroy' in 'remote-exec' but it didn't work for me.